# How to return specifi error level by clicking a button in a form of GUI in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, errorlevel

I am going to use GUI with a button click to return an error level with a specific number. It returns the error level value just for $Auto_Button, and the GUI disappears when the script executed.

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",13)

```
$MainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$MainForm.Text = "Process"
$MainForm.Width = 500
$MainForm.Height = 200
$MainForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$MainForm.BackColor = "#e2e2e2"

$Title = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Title.Font = $Font
$Title.Text = "Which process do you want to choose?"
$Title.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$Title.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,30)
$MainForm.Controls.Add($Title)

$Auto_Button = {$MainForm.Close()}
               Exit 10   

$Manual_Button = $MainForm.Close()}
               Exit 30

$Automatic = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Automatic.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,80)
$Automatic.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$Automatic.Text = "Automatically"
$Automatic.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Automatic.BackColor = "#e47104"
$Automatic.Add_Click($Auto_Button)
$MainForm.Controls.Add($Automatic)

$Manual = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Manual.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(270,80)
$Manual.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$Manual.Text = "Manually"
$Manual.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Manual.BackColor = "#e47104"
$Manual.Add_Click($Manual_Button)
$MainForm.Controls.Add($Manual)

$MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Usually such error messages have `Details` buttons which shows all information about the exception. There you'll see `System.Management.Automation.ExitException` which means that something has happened when you call `exit`.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: Why you have removed the code? As a generic answer: set some global variable to a specific value inside the button's handler function and then return this variable.

Comment: I updated the queestion

Comment: @montonero `ExitException` is what `exit` do. It is how PowerShell exits multiple nested levels of code, some of which can be not of PowerShell origin. But Windows Forms decide to handle everything and show fancy dialog box instead of passing exception to the caller.

Comment: @PetSerAl I believe your comment is for OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global variable for storing a result.

```
$Auto_Button = ({ $global:result=10
                  $MainForm.Close() })

$Manual_Button = ({ $global:result=20
                    $MainForm.Close() })

...

$result=0
$MainForm.ShowDialog()

$result | Out-File .\exit.txt
exit $result
```